# Peer reviewed stuff

Tags: discussion

Right now, we are in the early stage of this site. How do we go around deciding who reviews what stuff? For example, I added an excerpt for the `java` tag and it said that I have to wait to get it peer reviewed. Right now, there is no moderator and no one over 2k+ rep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Early sites start with a private beta that has significantly lowered privilege levels to help bootstrap the basic operation of the site.

While a Stack Exchange employee may fill in where Moderator (capital M) administration is needed, the primary roll of community-based moderation (small m) still falls on the early community. That is why private betas are somewhat contained to a smaller, formative audience — to help prepare this site with the structure and abilities needed on opening day (typically about three weeks from now, if all goes well).

See [**Help Center > Privileges**](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)

Answer (score 1):

There is a Community Moderator - an SE employee. With luck he will be here frequently over the next few days to help things move along. In private beta, the reputation thresholds are lower - I think significantly so...

Comment: Who is our CM for this site?

Comment: @thesecretmaster See the answer above.

Comment: Robert Cartaino?